# How to combine 2 responseEntity and return?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

how can i combine 2 different responseEntity and return

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getObject(@PathVariable("shopId") String shopId,
            @PathVariable("delearId") String delearId) {
        Shop objectToSave = (shopId.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) ? (null) : shopService.findOne(shopId);
        Delear objectName = (delearId.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) ? null : delearService.findOne(delearId);
        ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(objectName && objectToSave , HttpStatus.OK);// i want to combine both delear and shop

        if (objectName == null && objectToSave == null) {
        responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(objectName,objectToSave , HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return responseEntity;
    }
```

Comment: Combine them into one DTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make DTO class for response:

```
public class ResponseDto {

   private Shop shop;

   private Delear delear;

   // getters and setters
}
```

then

```
ResponseDto response = new ResponseDto();
response.setShop(shop);
response.setDelear(delear);
```

And then make your method `public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> getObject`...
and `return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);`